# Convert YUV NV21 to RGB in VideoSink

Tags: android, kotlin, opencv, webrtc, android-camera

Using the code bellow I manage to get NV21. So on output I get black and white image, it is possible that the chrominance (UV) data is not being handled correctly during rendering, leaving only the luminance (Y) data to be displayed.

```
    private fun startLocalVideoCapture(localSurfaceView: SurfaceViewRenderer) {
    val peerConnectionUtil = PeerConnectionUtil(
        requireActivity().application,
        eglBase.eglBaseContext
    )

    val peerConnectionFactory = peerConnectionUtil.peerConnectionFactory

    val localVideoSource by lazy { peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(false) }
    val localAudioSource by lazy { peerConnectionFactory.createAudioSource(MediaConstraints()) }
    val videoCapturer = createVideoCapturer()
    videoCapturer?.let { capturer ->
        val surfaceTextureHelper =
            SurfaceTextureHelper.create(Thread.currentThread().name, eglBase.eglBaseContext)
        capturer.initialize(
            surfaceTextureHelper,
            localSurfaceView.context,
            localVideoSource.capturerObserver
        )
        capturer.startCapture(
            WebRtcClient.VIDEO_HEIGHT,
            WebRtcClient.VIDEO_WIDTH,
            WebRtcClient.VIDEO_FPS
        )
    } ?: run {
        Log.e("Failed: ", "Failed to create video capturer")
    }

    localAudioTrack =
        peerConnectionFactory.createAudioTrack(
            WebRtcClient.LOCAL_TRACK_ID + WebRtcClient.AUDIO,
            localAudioSource
        )
    localVideoTrack =
        peerConnectionFactory.createVideoTrack(WebRtcClient.LOCAL_TRACK_ID, localVideoSource)

    val yuvToRgbVideoSink = YuvToRgbVideoSink(localSurfaceView)
    localVideoTrack?.addSink(yuvToRgbVideoSink)

    val localStream = peerConnectionFactory.createLocalMediaStream(WebRtcClient.LOCAL_STREAM_ID)
    localStream.addTrack(localVideoTrack)
    localStream.addTrack(localAudioTrack)
}
```

I've made `YuvToRgbVideoSink` class but I was unable to find correct way to convert it to RGB. Also I used OpenCV 4.6.0 but I am not profound in it.

```
    class YuvToRgbVideoSink(private val surfaceViewRenderer: SurfaceViewRenderer) : VideoSink {
    override fun onFrame(videoFrame: VideoFrame) {
        val buffer = videoFrame.buffer
        val width = buffer.width
        val height = buffer.height

        // Don't know how to use decodeYUV420SP or is it even correct
    }
    
    fun decodeYUV420SP(rgb: IntArray, yuv420sp: ByteArray, width: Int, height: Int)
    {
        val frameSize = width * height
        var j = 0
        var yp = 0
        while (j < height) {
            var uvp = frameSize + (j shr 1) * width
            var u = 0
            var v = 0
            var i = 0
            while (i < width)
            {
                var y = (0xff and yuv420sp[yp].toInt()) - 16
                if (y < 0)
                    y = 0
                if (i and 1 == 0) {
                    v = (0xff and yuv420sp[uvp++].toInt()) - 128
                    u = (0xff and yuv420sp[uvp++].toInt()) - 128
                }

                val y1192 = 1192 * y
                var r = y1192 + 1634 * v
                var g = y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u
                var b = y1192 + 2066 * u

                if (r < 0)
                    r = 0
                else if (r > 262143)
                    r = 262143
                if (g < 0)
                    g = 0
                else if (g > 262143)
                    g = 262143
                if (b < 0)
                    b = 0
                else if (b > 262143)
                    b = 262143

                rgb[yp] = -0x1000000 or (r shl 6 and 0xff0000) or (g shr 2 and 0xff00) or (b shr 10 and 0xff)
                i++
                yp++
            }
            j++
        }
    }
}
```